# Read JSON from API Response without Class in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

So, I am reading JSON from WordPress API and then read the contetnts. The JSON WP API returns is a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[
{
id: 8484,
date: "2022-03-12T21:00:00",
date_gmt: "2022-03-12T15:30:00",
modified: "2022-03-12T17:35:35",
modified_gmt: "2022-03-12T12:05:35",
slug: "5-ways-to-increase-leads-for-solar-companies",
status: "publish",
type: "post",
link: "https://inklik.com/blog/5-ways-to-increase-leads-for-solar-companies/",
},
{
id: 8484,
date: "2022-03-12T21:00:00",
date_gmt: "2022-03-12T15:30:00",
modified: "2022-03-12T17:35:35",
modified_gmt: "2022-03-12T12:05:35",
slug: "5-ways-to-increase-leads-for-solar-companies",
status: "publish",
type: "post",
link: "https://inklik.com/blog/5-ways-to-increase-leads-for-solar-companies/",
},
{
id: 8484,
date: "2022-03-12T21:00:00",
date_gmt: "2022-03-12T15:30:00",
modified: "2022-03-12T17:35:35",
modified_gmt: "2022-03-12T12:05:35",
slug: "5-ways-to-increase-leads-for-solar-companies",
status: "publish",
type: "post",
link: "https://inklik.com/blog/5-ways-to-increase-leads-for-solar-companies/",
}
]
```

I tried reading it like this:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://www." + domain.Text() + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/")
Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
link_status.Text = json.SelectToken(0).SelectToken("id")
```

But it is not working. I want to iterate through all the data in the API. All the examples I have seen so far are very complicated. Can I do this without using a class? Thanks

Comment: What has VB6 to do with this? -- Why *without using a class*?

Comment: I am looking shorter way to get data from JSON keys ... like we do in Python.

Comment: @Jimi I am new to VB thought they are the same thing

Comment: *like we do in Python*: who's *we*? You can deserialize to class objects in Python, too. -- No they're definitely not the same thing. -- You have a Json Array there, not an Json Object -- You can deserialze your JSON to a (very simple) model and use a `List(Of [Your mode])`, loop the list and get the values from strongly typed properties (for each object, when you press the *dot*, Intellisense will tell you which Properties are available and their Type and you can assign / use the value directly).

Comment: If you want to try it, pass your JSON to [Json Utils](https://jsonutils.com/), you'll get a model in VB.Net language, then deserialize to a List of this model. All done. -- With a structure simple as this one, if you use Visual Studio or similar, you can also use the internal tool: `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an array in json, so use this code

```
Dim json As JArray = JArray.Parse(result)
link_status.Text = json(0).SelectToken("id");
```

Comment: ` Dim a As JArray = JArray.Parse(result)
        For Each o As JObject In a.Children(Of JObject)()
            link_status.Text += o.SelectToken("id").ToString() + vbNewLine
        Next`
Combining yours and I find some example on YouTube. Thank you, now it works as I wanted it to be.